# Running another activity from xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

Basically I'm just trying to run a class which is called NotificationReceiverActivity from another Activity class, but nothing shows up on the screen when I click on the button to run the activity class, I feel like I'm being a total noob on the xml part of the code and here is the AndroidManifest.xml ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.vogella.android.notificationmanager"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="de.vogella.android.notificationmanager.CreateNotificationActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="de.vogella.android.notificationmanager.NotificationReceiverActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

The main activity which is CreateNotificationActivity class, works and turns on flawlessly.

Java code for the main activity;

```
public class CreateNotificationActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void createNotification(View view) {
// Prepare intent which is triggered if the
// notification is selected
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

// Build notification
// Actions are just fake
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
    .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)

    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Call", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "More", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "And more", pIntent).build();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// hide the notification after its selected
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

}
}
```

And the NotificationReceiverActivity class;

```
   public class NotificationReceiverActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private final String CLASSNAME = getClass().getSimpleName();

   Camera cam = null;
   ImageButton ib1;
   Parameters para;
   PowerManager pm;
   WakeLock wl;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
       wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "whatever");
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       wl.acquire();
       initialize();
      ib1.setOnClickListener(this);
       Log.i(CLASSNAME, "CREATING NOW"+cam);
   }

   private void initialize() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       ib1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib2);
   }

   public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (cam == null) {
    cam = Camera.open();
    para = cam.getParameters();
    para.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    cam.setParameters(para);
    Log.i(CLASSNAME, "AA"+cam);

} else {
    para.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    cam.setParameters(para);
    cam.release();
    cam = null;
    Log.i(CLASSNAME, "BB"+cam);

}
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPause();
wl.release();
cam=cam;
finish();
   }
@Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
    cam=cam;

 }


}
```

And the top 4 lines of the log cat;

```
01-31 06:11:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(29533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 06:11:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(29533): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.vogella.android.notificationmanager/de.vogella.android.notificationmanager.NotificationReceiverActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10181 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
01-31 06:11:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(29533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
01-31 06:11:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(29533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
```

Comment: Post the Java code from activities as well.

Comment: Try to remove `<intent-filter>...`</intent-filter>` part from your second `activity` element

Comment: u nee the wakelock permission in you manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

Comment: And <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />   But that wasn't it, with both classes I was setting the layout to the same xml, althought I have made two different layout files, I have solved it thanks to your guidance!

Comment: glad that it worked for you. If you found the answer helpful, please accept it so the question can be closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the intent filter from your NotificationReceiverActivity.

to use a button to start NotificationReceiverActivity from you  CreateNotificationActivity you have to assign a clicklistener to that button in you activity

This is an example of this

```
public class CreateNotificationActivity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

         Intent intent = new Intent(CreateNotificationActivity.this,NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);


        }

    });

}

}
```

Comment: I get a lot of errors if I remove it, and i can't even post that many characters into comment, I've just updated my question with the two classes.

Comment: have you included the imports?   change the name of you xml to your activity's xml file and make sure the id of button matches to what is in your xml file